# mvc 4 determine Controllers Count

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Oracle DB that Contains 50 Table  i'm Confused how to determine number of Controllers to use in my web application.
Knowing that every table have the same operation add ,insert,update,delete but different in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend of your design. First you have to start with the Models and then you will see which models require controllers.

Comment: i think that i can make one controller i'm doing my research about it to make sure that it works well or not

Comment: I will not suggest you to do one controller. Regarding Maintenance. Let say you have a client table or Employer table or Merchandise table you will access to everything just by calling one controller let say `Clientcontroller`? And don't forget that MVC is based on naming convention over configuration.

Comment: i have in my template menu which contains 5 item and each item have drop down with different number of items 
i'm thinking to make controller to each item in main menu what do you think about this ?

Comment: Yes you can do 5 `Controllers`. if Items are not related between them. Depends You can also do one `Controller` with 5 different `Actions` for each items. Can I see the code so. It will be easier to interpret.